# Getting 'undefined', can't figure out why

Tags: javascript

Working my way through 'Eloquent Javascript' and I'm hitting a bit of a roadblock in understanding how to properly use `if` with `for` statements in the language.  I'm supposed to write a function that counts all instances of the uppercase 'B' in a given string.  The code I've written thus far:

```js
function countBs(s) {
  var counter = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if ('B' == s.charAt(i)) {}
    counter += 1;
  }
}

console.log(countBs("BBC"));
```

**expected output**: `2`

**actual output**: `undefined`

Is my loop going wrong, or my 'if'?

Comment: You are not returning `counter`.

Comment: It is like that : if (s.charAt(i) == 'B')

Comment: return counter, you are not returning anything from function

Comment: That's also wrong: `if ('B' == s.charAt(i)) {  }counter += 1;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You have two bugs**

1. You are incrementing your `counter` outside of the if statement.
2. You have no `return` statement.

The following can be used:

```
function countBs(s){
  var counter = 0;

  for(i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
    if ('B' == s.charAt(i)) {
      counter += 1; // this needs to be inside the if statement
    }
  }

  return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function does not have a `return` statement.

Comment: oh wow.  Cannot believe I missed that. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 1):

A few issues.

```js
function countBs(s) {
  var counter = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if ('B' == s.charAt(i)) {
      ++counter;
    }
  }
  return counter;
}

document.write(countBs("BBC"));
```

1. You were not returning `counter` at the end of the function
2. Your `if` statement was opened, then immediately closed, so nothing happens if the character was `B`
3. Even if you returned `counter` and fixed the above 2 errors, the function still would have exited after 1 `B` was found.  To fix this, move the `return` after the `for` ends.

If you're interested, the same problem can be solved with this one-liner:

```js
function countBs(s) {
  return s.match(/B/g).length;
}

document.write(countBs("BBC"));
```

Which finds all `B` characters (case-sensitive), puts them into an array, then returns how many items are in that array.

Comment: There was no return statement originally, why would it have exited early?

Comment: @TbWill4321 If he followed some of the earlier replies and comments to add a `return`, it would have still been executing inside the `for`.  Looks like the original question has been edited for clarity, so my third point loses a bit of its meaning.